# how to use domain address instead of IP for dns

Tags: dns, bind9, vesta

I have ubuntu server on Digitalocean with Vestacp installed on domain.ltd
In my domain panel i pointed dns to my server IP (000.000.000.000).
I want to have multiple websites on this server, the problem is that i don't want to point my server ip, instead i want to use ns1.domain.ltd and ns2.domain.ltd for dns addresses in my domains panels.

This is my domain.ltd bind9 settings:

```
$TTL 14400
@    IN    SOA    ns1.domain.ltd.    root.domain.ltd. (
                                            2018011309
                                            7200
                                            3600
                                            1209600
                                            180 )

@   14400   IN  NS      ns1.domain.ltd.
@   14400   IN  NS      ns2.domain.ltd.
@   14400   IN  A       000.000.000.000
www 14400   IN  A       000.000.000.000
ftp 14400   IN  A       000.000.000.000
mail    14400   IN  A       000.000.000.000
smtp    14400   IN  A       000.000.000.000
pop 14400   IN  A       000.000.000.000
imap    14400   IN  A       000.000.000.000
@   14400   IN  MX  10  mail.domain.ltd.
@   14400   IN  TXT     "v=spf1 a mx ip4:000.000.000.000 ~all"
_dmarc  14400   IN  TXT     "v=DMARC1; p=none"
ns1 14400   IN  NS      000.000.000.000.
ns2 14400   IN  NS      000.000.000.000.
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use [CNAME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record)

for example you have domain, domain1.com

```
@   14400   IN  A       000.000.000.000
```

then for the other domain zone record, domain2.com

```
@   14400   IN  CNAME       domain1.com
```

Comment: CNAME record is not allowed for the root domain. Your second example is invalid.